# Сайт периодически выдает ошибку 500

Tags: modx

Народ помогите когда лазишь по сайту периодически выкидывает 500-ую ошибку.

[Сайт](http://dinast.testkolibri.ru/) на Modx.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, yuzik.74@gmail.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache Server at dinast.testkolibri.ru Port 80

Comment: yuzik.74@gmail.com это вы?

Comment: клиента, а это важно ?